# Correct location for title Director?

Tags: word-order

Correct usage of department director?
Example:

- Director of Human Resources
- Human Resources Director

Comment: A person at that level should have an official title. You're best off using that.

Comment: Either is correct. Some companies use "Director of X" and others use "X Director". Just be consistent.

Comment: Even ignoring the fact that those are not titles, but job despriptions or roles, there is no general rule. Whether Joe Soap is D or HR or HRD is a choice for the employer ot make and never anything else. By the way, how does "location" come into that, please?

Answer (score -1):

- Director of Human Resources

strikes me as more correct and formal. *That said, you're in the realm of corporate idiom, so there are no binding rules.*